# Nested For loop in Django html template to create cards groups

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I'm trying to do a script to create cards groups in my Django project.

I send "my*list" data to frontend and I want to use also "my*_dict" data to create nested for loop.

I think I'm using a script that is not supported in templating.

The logic is good but syntax is wrong and I can't find a right way to solve (also because I'm a beginner).

```
my_dict = [
  {
    "idToolGroup_id": 2,
    "idToolName": 2,
    "ToolName": "Tool 02",
  },
  {
    "idToolGroup_id": 2,
    "idToolName": 3,
    "ToolName": "Tool 03",
  }
]


my_list = [
  [
    {
      "idToolGroup_id": 2,
      "idToolName_id": 2,
      "idTable": 3,
      "TableName": "Table 3",
      "LinkToolPage": "TOOL03"
    },
    {
      "idToolGroup_id": 2,
      "idToolName_id": 2,
      "idTable": 4,
      "TableName": "Table 4",
      "LinkToolPage": "TOOL04"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "idToolGroup_id": 2,
      "idToolName_id": 3,
      "idTable": 5,
      "TableName": "Table 5",
      "LinkToolPage": "TOOL05"
    },
    {
      "idToolGroup_id": 2,
      "idToolName_id": 3,
      "idTable": 6,
      "TableName": "Table 6",
      "LinkToolPage": "TOOL06"
    }
  ]
]
```

Script I'm using is the following but doesn't work:

```
  {% for index, tool in enumerate(my_dict) %}
  
    <div class="RowGroup">

      <div class="Block1">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"> {{ tool.ToolName }} </h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="Block2">

        {% for item in my_list[index] %}
              
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.TableName }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text"></p>
              <a href="{{ item.LinkToolPage }}" class="btn btn-primary">Open tool</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        {% endfor %}
      </div>

    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

I want to obtain this final result:
The code has to be dynamic because data came from database so I can have more "Tool Group" and different number of "Tables".
[image]

Comment: You should use two nested for loops. The outer loop iterates over the `my_dict` list and retrieves each tool dictionary. We use the `enumerate` function to also get the index of the `tool` object in the list. I dumped the code [here](https://www.codedump.xyz/js/ZAyQxtRAsbaCyc8u) at codedump.xyz kindly check it and if works then tell me.

Comment: It's best to have this kind of logic in views and the structure that is passed to the templates should be as close to how you want to display it as possible. For this it's best to construct a list/dict that would combine all the values and thus would be easier to navigate in the template.